# My getView method is not getting called for populating datas in listview

Tags: java, android

```
public class ListDetails extends ListActivity 
{
    ImageButton imagebutton;
    LoanDetails details;
    ArrayList<String> CreateReqID1, OpenTime1, RequestSummary1, RequestStatus1;
    TextView CreateReqID, OpenTime, RequestSummary, RequestStatus;
    ListView list;
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {       
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.listdetails);           



            CreateReqID1 =  (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getExtras().get("details1");
            OpenTime1 = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getExtras().get("details2");
            RequestSummary1 = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getExtras().get("details3");
            RequestStatus1 = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getExtras().get("details4");

            setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.requestlistview));        
            }

     private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

            public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
                super(context, resource);           

            }
                @Override
                public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    final View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.requestlistview, parent, false);


                    Log.i("values set", "success");
                    CreateReqID = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.createReq);
                    OpenTime = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.openTime);
                    RequestSummary = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.requestSumary);
                    RequestStatus = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.status);


                    CreateReqID.setText(CreateReqID1.get(position));
                    OpenTime.setText(OpenTime1.get(position));  
                    RequestSummary.setText(RequestSummary1.get(position));
                    RequestStatus.setText(RequestStatus1.get(position));        

                    return row;
                }           
            }
}
```

I have the above code to add data's into listview but my getview method is not getting called please tell me why.

my listview xml is shown below

```
<ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" >
```

and my list layout format is shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFFFF" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_x="10dp"
        android:layout_y="60dp"
        android:text="RequestSummary"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textColorLink="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:layout_x="10dp"
        android:layout_y="85dp"
        android:text="RequestStatus"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textColorHint="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:layout_x="10dp"
        android:layout_y="35dp"
        android:text="OpenTime"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_x="10dp"
        android:layout_y="10dp"
        android:text="CreateReqID"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/createReq"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textColorHint="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/requestSumary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/createReq"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/requestSumary"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/openTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/createReq"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to populate the textviews dynamically i got everything in the arraylist but my getView method is not getting called.

Comment: Probably You need to override getCount() at least to let ListView know that adapter is not empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not passing the array of string to the `ArrayAdapter`.. `ArrayAdapter` use the passed list to calculate the number of item to display in the view..

Check out the javadoc for [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html). You either need to send the array of object to its constructor or call one of the [add()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#add%28T%29) method to add the object to the Adapter..

Answer (score 1):

You missed the `getCount()` method of adatper.Just override the getCount method and return   appropriate count.Following method will force your getView to be called 5 times

```
@Override
    public synchronized int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }
```